# Работа с Page. Переключение и передача данных между страницами

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Доброго времени суток, Господа. У меня есть приложение, в окне которого, содержатся фреймы. У меня есть две страницы - первая MainPage содержит меню с выбором категорий, и собственно сам контент выбранной категории, разные изделия.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Каждое изделие является кнопкой, по нажатию на которой должна сработать команда и открыться новая страница с заполненными данными о том изделии, которое является выбранным.

Вопросы:
1. Как правильно переключаться между страницами, чтобы не было костылей?
2. Как правильно передавать данные между страницами? 
3. (Дополнительный вопрос) Как сделать у контролов TextBox двусвязную привязку? Чтобы по изменению данных в TextBox, она отражалась на определенном свойстве в VM.

Все эти вопросы хотелось бы услышать с подходом MVVM. Для всех страниц, которые у меня есть, уже сделаны VM.

Comment: Здесь принято на каждый вопрос создавать отдельный. Для множественных, размытых вопросов есть чаты. [F#](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f), [C#](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--) и [другие](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Если вы хотите использовать отдельные VM для каждой из страниц, то работа с Frame&Page подразумевает использование `NavigationService` для навигации между страницами, это в свою очередь усложняет передачу данных между страницами, ее конечно можно передавать, но через конструктор страницы понадобиться передавать данные в конструктор VM соотв.страницы. Короче, вариант с  Frame&Page лучше всего работает когда вы имеете одну общую на все страницы VM. А то, что вы хотите сделать проще всего достичь с помощью отображения набора `UserControl`ов. Это сугубо мое личное мнение, конечно.

Comment: У меня есть одна общая VM для всех страниц. Но для каждой страницы есть своя VM тоже

Comment: @Bulson Это не очень удобное решение. Я сделал класс PageNavigator : IPageNavigator, который реализует метод `void Next<T,U>( U data ) where T : Page`, через него я осуществляю переходы между страницами, и страницы хранятся в PageNavigator. Но вот как передать `U data`, я не могу догадаться. Только правильно нужно сделать; идея с передачей `U data` в Tag страницы не очень идея